# MySQL query for today's date not working

Tags: php, mysql

What I am doing wrong with below statement

```
$Sql = "SELECT DateOfInvCreated FROM invoice_list 
    WHERE username = '$username' AND (DateOfInvCreated >= CURDATE() AND DateOfInvCreated < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)";
```

and I also tried

```
$date_vmd = date("Y-m-d"); 
 $Sql = "SELECT DateOfInvCreated FROM invoice_list username = '$username' AND (DateOfInvCreated BETWEEN '$date 00:00:00' AND '$date 23:59:59)"
```

which gives me this error "Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in"

```
$Sql = "SELECT DateOfInvCreated FROM invoice_list 
        WHERE username = '$username' AND DATE(DateOfInvCreated) = CURDATE()";
```

which less efficient.
First and third query gives me only single result instead of many.
What I have wrong here ?
DateOfInvCreated is timestamp. **Edit:** I am adding an  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyel6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your second query you're missing the `where` clause as you can see below.

```
$date_vmd = date("Y-m-d"); 
$Sql = "SELECT DateOfInvCreated FROM invoice_list username = '$username' AND (DateOfInvCreated BETWEEN '$date 00:00:00' AND '$date 23:59:59)"
```

You should try running these queries directly in MYSQL, you might be getting back the full results, but you think you're only getting back one, based on the rest of the code you're not showing.

Comment: thnx @henry for suggesting running these queries directly in MYSQL the query was fine :) . I think there was an error in query statement.I just rewrite this whole part.2nd & 3rd are now working fine .